# ASP.NET BlogEngine Requires Additional Dlls

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, blogengine.net

I have DevExpress controls implemented in the core website and the dlls are stored in `/<websitedomain>/bin`.  I've installed BlogEngine in an application folder at `/<websitedomain>/Blog/` and the necessary BlogEngine dlls go into `/<websitedomain>/Blog/bin`.

Why does BlogEngine require the DevExpress controls in `/<websitedomain>/Blog/bin` ?

Is it a specific IIS6 or web.config issue?

Answer (score 0):

BlogEngine itself does not require DevExpress controls.

Does any of your pages or posts are using DevExpress controls?

Do you have any custom made "Standalone" pages in the /blog directory?

Something in your folder /blog is using the control this requiring the dlls to it.
Search and find what is using it.

Do you have a web.config  in the /blog  and then the root?

That can also be an issue if you are using the same web.config for both.

Comment: No pages or posts use the DevExpress controls.

Comment: There are no standalone pages in the /blog directory or any references to the DevExpress dlls can be found in the /blog directory.

Comment: There is a web.config in the core root web directory and also in the /blog directory.

Comment: Note: If I remove the core website and just run /blog as an application in the website, then everything works ok.

Comment: And similarly, if I add the DevExpress controls to the /blog/bin/ then everything works ok.